# connect the Xamarian form application to the database the is in google cloud

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to connect the Xamarian form application to the database the is in google cloud but it is not working this is my code the entered the ip address and username of the database and the database name and all of this data is correct and the same of the server information

```
    public void try1() {var connectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder("Host=myip.8;Uid=sqlserver;Pwd=mypass;Database=nasel")
    {
        // Connecting to a local proxy that does not support ssl.
        SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None,
    };
    DbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        // Define the SQL statement to insert data into the 'parent' table.
        var sql = "INSERT INTO parent (Parent_CPR, first_name, last_name, mobile, email) VALUES (@Parent_CPR, @first_name, @last_name, @mobile, @email)";

        // Create a new MySqlCommand object and set its Connection property.
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, (MySqlConnection) connection);

        // Add parameters to the MySqlCommand object.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parent_CPR", "1234567890");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", "John");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", "Doe");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", "1234567890");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "john.doe@example.com");

        // Execute the SQL INSERT statement.
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Rows affected: " + rowsAffected);

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the connection process.
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a helpful description.  What is the problem?  Do you get an error or exception?  Connecting directly to a db server from a mobile app is an extremely bad practice and you should avoid it.

Comment: what you advice me to do

Comment: generally you use a web service as an intermediate layer